# How to properly join tailwind css classes using clsx?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to join tailwind classes and apply them to a button using [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx). One class is applied by default `'rounded-none'` and the other one is passed in as a prop

```
const Button = ({
  children, ...props
}): JSX.Element => {

  return (
    <ADButton
      className={clsx('rounded-none', props.className)}
      {...props}
    >
      {children}
    </ADButton>
  );
};
```

Let's say I have added `padding-top: 0px;` to the button like shown below

```
<Button
  color="primary"
  className="pt-0"
>
  {t('btn.add')}
</Button>
```

The joined className should look like `'rounded-none pt-0'`. If no className prop is passed, then just apply ‘rounded-none’

The problem am having right now is ‘rounded-none’ only gets applied to buttons without className prop. On buttons with className prop, only className prop gets applied but not ‘rounded-none’. How can I fix this so that both classes are joined and applied to the button?

Answer (score 16):

You could use a merge of clsx and twMerge [twMerge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwind-merge) to efficiently merge Tailwind CSS classes in JS without style conflict.
Be carefull to dont override your previous classes

```
import clsx, { ClassValue } from 'clsx'
import { twMerge } from 'tailwind-merge'
export const cn = (...classes: ClassValue[]) => twMerge(clsx(...classes))
```

Answer (score 5):

You're having this issue because the default prop of `ADButton` is set to `className` and the extra prop you're passing to the Button component is set to `className` as well. In effect, you are **overriding** the default `className` with your newly passed `className` prop. If there are are 2 similarly named props, React will choose the one that is declared later in the event of a conflict.

So this:

```
<ADButton
      className={clsx('rounded-none', 'pt-0')}
// I am declared later so I win
      className='pt-0'
    >
      {children}
    </ADButton>
```

becomes:

```
<ADButton
      className="pt-0"
    >
      {children}
    </ADButton>
```

Here's one solution:

```
const Button = ({
  children, ...props
}) => {
  const { classNameDestructured = "", ...rest } = props;
  return (
    <ADButton
      className={clsx('rounded-none', classNameDestructured)}
      {...rest}
    >
      {children}
    </ADButton>
  );
};
```

You destructure `props` and set a default for `classNameDestructured`. This allows you to declare `Button` without additional props:

```
<Button>
  {t('btn.add')}
</Button>
```

Then you pass `classNameDestructured` as an argument to your `clsx()` function. Your additional classes are then joined and applied to the button.

This works because `className` isn't declared twice as a prop in `ADButton` anymore so we've eliminated the **overriding** conflict.

Answer (score 4):

You can combine both `clsx` and `twMerge`

**Utility Function** `/lib/utils.ts`

```
import { type ClassValue, clsx } from "clsx"
import { twMerge } from "tailwind-merge"
 
export function cn(...inputs: ClassValue[]) {
  return twMerge(clsx(inputs))
}
```

**Use it as** `page.tsx`

```
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
export default function Component(){
   return <div className={cn(
              "bg-black font-sans",
              "bg-white h-full", 
               {
                 "px-5":pending, // if pending is true apply padding
               }
           )}
         />
}
```

For explanation refer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76660733/13431819
- [cn() - Every Tailwind Coder Needs It (clsx + twMerge)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=re2JFITR7TI)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you put the `{...props}` after the `className` attribute. The `className` gets overridden by the className in the `props`.

The simple solution is to move the `{...props}` before the `className`.

```js
const Button = ({
  children, ...props
}): JSX.Element => {

  return (
    <ADButton
      {...props}
      className={clsx('rounded-none', props.className)}
    >
      {children}
    </ADButton>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

- You shouldn't use reserved names. Even if className isn't properly 'reserved' you could avoid conflict by renaming your props and make things easier to debug : "classes", "appendClasses", "additionnalClasses", "optClasses" etc...
- I recommend you a recent library - [CSS COMPONENTS](https://www.css-components.net/) - for easily create components and variants. You can use it with your favorite CSS library, such as tailwind.
  I actually find it perfect for tailwindCSS.

All the best