# Why does my tailwindscss utility class not work in my nextjs component?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

Can someone make me understand why this is not working ?
I imported my utility class as a string from my data file.
I'm using tailwindcss
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWvGj.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTyYf.png)

Comment: Duplicate of -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69687530/dynamically-build-classnames-in-tailwindcss

There are a few options listed there, but in short, **you cant have dynamic css clases on tailwindcss**

Comment: Other option -> https://twind.dev/

Comment: Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72185444/change-colour-of-nextjs-tailwind-component-based-on-prop/72185577#72185577 Similar to this