# Change colour of nextjs - tailwind component based on prop

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am creating an alert component in nextjs with tailwindcss to display some information. Ultimately I would like to pass a a prop "alert_type" to this component and based on that change the colour of the alert. (The example below does not have this functionality yet). In the example below I would expect the colour of my alert to be green however, it is not picking up the colour specifications. I don't understand why this is not working...

```
export function Success({ title, children }: AlertProps) {
  const colour = 'green'
  return (
    <div className={`rounded-md p-4 bg-${colour}-50`}>
      <div className="flex">
        <div className="flex-shrink-0">
          <CheckCircleIcon
            className={'h-5 w-5' + ' text-' + colour + '-400'}
            aria-hidden="true"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="ml-3">
          <h3 className={'text-sm font-medium' + ' text-' + colour + '-800'}>
            {title}
          </h3>
          <div className={'mt-2 text-sm' + ' text-' + colour + '-700'}>
            {children}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the complete string as tailwind only parses the complete string. So for instance , like you are using `bg-${colour}-500` will be replaced with `${first_var}` where you have to define `const first_var = bg-green-500`;

Then for each time you have to create a new variable like for `text-colour-700` and `text-colour-800`,

Define like this

```
const sec_var = 'text-green-700';
const third_var = 'text-green-800';
```

Comment: Glad, I helped you