# How to use variables in Tailwind peer & peer/checked

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I know that we can differentiate peer/peer-checked using names like `peer/{name}` ([doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#differentiating-peers)). I want to use a variable as a name, something like :class="`peer/${VARIABLE}`" but it seems to be not working. Is there a proper way to use a variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically build classnames in TailwindCss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69687530/dynamically-build-classnames-in-tailwindcss)