# Trouble with Dynamic Color in Tailwind Component

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm having trouble understanding why the blue color is not working in my component. Could you please help me troubleshoot this issue on Stack Overflow? I have a Tag component that should apply different background and text colors based on the color prop provided. However, when I set the color prop to "blue", the expected blue color is not being applied to the component. I have tried various solutions, including dynamically constructing the class names and using the correct syntax for Tailwind CSS classes. However, I have been unsuccessful in resolving the issue. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

````js
    import React from "react";
    
    export default function Tag({ index, tag, color = "red" }) {
      return (
        <li
          key={index}
          className={`inline-flex items-center rounded-full px-3 py-2 text-xs font-bold uppercase bg-${color}-200 text-${color}-700`}
        >
          <a href={`/?=${tag.text.replace(/\s/g, "_").toLowerCase()}`}>
            {tag.text}
          </a>
        </li>
      );
    }```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically build classnames in TailwindCss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69687530/dynamically-build-classnames-in-tailwindcss)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could:

- Have the entire class in the variable you pass to `className` like

  ```
  export default function Tag({ index, tag, color = "bg-red-200 text-red-700" }) {
    return (
      <li
        key={index}
        className={`… ${color}`}
       >
  ```
- Have a dictionary for `color` to Tailwind class names:

  ```
  export default function Tag({ index, tag, color = "red" }) {
    const DICTIONARY = {
      red: 'bg-red-200 text-red-700',
      // …
    };
    // …
    return (
      <li
        key={index}
        className={`… ${DICTIONARY[color]}`}
       >
  ```
- Use the `style` attribute for truly dynamic colors, if `theme` can be converted to a valid CSS color value (or you could [get the color from Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#referencing-in-java-script)):

  ```
  export default function Tag({ index, tag, color = "red" }) {
    const styles = {
      // Convert from `color` variable
    };
    // …
    return (
      <li
        key={index}
        className="…"
        style={style}
       >
  ```
- [`safelist` the classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes), if you have a limited number of known colors:

  ```js
  module.exports = {
    safelist: [
      { pattern: /^text-(red|green|blue)-700$/ },
      { pattern: /^bg-(red|green|blue)-200$/ },
      // …
    ],
    // …
  ];
  ```