# How to dynamically pass tailwind styles from props

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js, tailwind-variants

I am sending a tailwind color `green-500` from the prop `bgColor` and then use it inside the `after:border-b-${bgColor}` in the `positionStyles` object.

But tailwind is unable to dynamically parse `after:border-b-${bgColor}` as a tailwind class.

How to solve this issue? I am open to new suggestions or ways to rewrite my code.

What I want is to pass just a color like `green-500` and then let tailwind render it as a class.

Following is my code:

```
const TOOLTIP_POSITIONS = {
  TOP: "TOP",
  RIGHT: "RIGHT",
  BOTTOM: "BOTTOM",
  LEFT: "LEFT",
};

const ToolTip = ({
  title,
  position = TOOLTIP_POSITIONS.BOTTOM,
  isOverflowX = false,
  noTooltip = false,
  zindex,
  bgColor = "green-500",
  keys = [],
  children,
}) => {

  const positionStyles = {
    [TOOLTIP_POSITIONS.BOTTOM]: `top-[100%] mt-2
    after:content-[""] 
    after:absolute
    after:top-[-5px]
    after:left-2/4
    after:-translate-x-2/4
    after:w-0
    after:h-0
    after:border-l-[6px] after:border-l-transparent
    after:border-b-[6px] after:border-b-${bgColor}
    after:border-r-[6px] after:border-r-transparent`,
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={`tooltip-wrapper group relative flex w-full items-center justify-center font-medium`}
    >
      {children}
      <div
        className={`tooltip absolute hidden w-max rounded-lg bg-gray950 p-2 text-center text-white group-hover:flex group-hover:items-center ${positionStyles[position]}`}
      >
        {title}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: twMerge does  exactly what you are looking for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble with Dynamic Color in Tailwind Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76353036/trouble-with-dynamic-color-in-tailwind-component)

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could:

- Have the entire class in the `bgColor` prop like

  ```
  const ToolTip = ({
    …
    bgColor = "after:border-b-green-500",
    …
  }) => {
    const positionStyles = {
      [TOOLTIP_POSITIONS.BOTTOM]: `
      …
      after:border-b-[6px] ${bgColor}
      …`,
    };
  ```
- Have a dictionary for `color` to Tailwind class names:

  ```
  const ToolTip = ({
    …
    bgColor = "green-500",
    …
  }) => {
    const DICTIONARY = {
      'green-500': 'after:border-b-green-500',
      // …
    };
    const positionStyles = {
      [TOOLTIP_POSITIONS.BOTTOM]: `
      …
      after:border-b-[6px] ${DICTIONARY[bgColor]}
      …`,
    };
  ```
- Use the `style` attribute for truly dynamic colors, if `theme` can be converted to a valid CSS color value (or you could [get the color from Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#referencing-in-java-script)):

  ```
  import resolveConfig from 'tailwindcss/resolveConfig';
  import tailwindConfig from './tailwind.config.js';

  const fullConfig = resolveConfig(tailwindConfig);

  // …

  const ToolTip = ({
    …
    bgColor = "green-500",
    …
  }) => {
    const positionStyles = {
      [TOOLTIP_POSITIONS.BOTTOM]: `
      …
      after:border-b-[6px] after:border-b-[color:--color]
      …`,
    };

    return (
      <div …>
        {children}
        <div
          className={`… ${positionStyles[position]}`}
          style={{
            '--color': fullConfig.theme.borderColor[bgColor] || fullConfig.theme.borderColor[bgColor.split('-')[0]][bgColor.split('-')[1]],
          }}
        >
  ```
- [`safelist` the classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes), if you have a limited number of known colors:

  ```js
  module.exports = {
    safelist: [
      {
        pattern: /^border-b-(red|green|blue)-500$/,
        variants: ['after'],
      },
      // …
    ],
    // …
  ];
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `after:border-b-${bgColor}` the whole class name should be variable meaning

```
let bgColor = "border-b-red-200" // whole className should be static

const positionStyles = {
   // ..other classes
   after:${bgColor}
   `,
};
```