# How can I added function in tailwindcss class

Tags: reactjs, function, tailwind-css

I want to added a function to tailwindcss class.
such as,
I have a list Tags. And I want to added a function as like as class.
But it not work
My function Name **randomColor**
**randomColor** function i want to add as like tailwindcss class

**My code is**

```
{task?.tags?.length > 0 &&
                      task?.tags?.map((tag) => (
                        <li key={tag}>
                          <span
                            className={`inline-block h-5 whitespace-nowrap rounded-[45px]  px-2.5  text-sm capitalize text-[#F4F5F6]  bg-[${**randomColor()**}]`}
                          >
                            {tag}
                          </span>
                        </li>
                      ))}
```

**My function is,**

```
const bgColor = [
    "#0B956C",
    "#1C6FBD",
    "#BC1C1E",
    "#8D4615",
    "#0695B7",
    "#6110A7",
    "#99630F",
    "#14B9B2",
    "#99630F",
  ];

  export function randomColor() {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * bgColor.length) + 1;
    const data = bgColor[randomNumber];
    if (data === undefined) {
      return bgColor[1];
    }
    return data;
  }
```

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble with Dynamic Color in Tailwind Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76353036/trouble-with-dynamic-color-in-tailwind-component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`**randomColor()**` is incorrect JavaScript syntax. You may have meant `randomColor()` as in:

```html
<span
  className={`… bg-[${randomColor()}]`}
>
```

Furthermore, as per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could:

- Have the entire class in the `bgColor` array like:

  ```js
  const bgColor = [
    "bg-[#0B956C]",
    "bg-[#1C6FBD]",
    "bg-[#BC1C1E]",
    "bg-[#8D4615]",
    "bg-[#0695B7]",
    "bg-[#6110A7]",
    "bg-[#99630F]",
    "bg-[#14B9B2]",
    "bg-[#99630F]",
  ];
  ```

  ```
  <span
    className={`… ${randomColor()}`}
  >
  ```

  Also, ensure the file that the `randomColor()` function is in is covered by the `content` file globs in the Tailwind configuration.
- Use the `style` attribute:

  ```
  <span
    className={`…`}
    style={{
      backgroundColor: randomColor(),
    }}
  >
  ```