# Am I doing passing this prop wrong?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, tailwind-css, web-frontend

I'm creating a website using react and tailwind CSS, I don't know why hover on button is not working.
I added my custom colors all the props but `hoverColor` are okay, also I don't know why the react icon doesn't work for me.

```js
import React from "react";


function Button(props) {

    return (
        <button
            className={`px-4 py-2 rounded w-max mx-2 ${props.bgColor} ${props.textColor} hover:${props.hoverColor}`}>
            {props.text}
        </button>

    );
}

export default Button;
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import { IoPersonOutline } from "react-icons/io5";
import Button from './Button';




function Navbar() {

    return (
        <nav className="flex items-center justify-between h-16 bg-white px-4 shadow-sm">

            <div className="flex items-center my-2">


                <Button bgColor="bg-red" text="Post Ad"><span className="flex items-center gap-2"><IoPersonOutline /></span>
                </Button>
                <Button hoverColor='bg-gray' textColor='text-dark-gray' text='Blue' />
                <Button hoverColor='bg-light-gray' textColor='text-dark-gray' text='Blue' />
                <Button hoverColor='bg-light-gray' textColor='text-dark-gray' text='Blue' />

            </div>
            <div className="flex items-center my-2">

                <input type="text" placeholder="Searching in all..." className="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-light-gray text-current" />
                <Button textColor="text-dark-gray" text="Search" />
                <Button textColor="text-dark-gray" text="Settings" />

                <div className="sm:w-px h-8 mx-5 bg-gray"></div>
                <h1 className=" text-xl font-bold mr-2 text-red">Divar</h1>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

I've done everything I know, but nothing has changed. Please let me know if you can identify what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble with Dynamic Color in Tailwind Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76353036/trouble-with-dynamic-color-in-tailwind-component)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could:

- Have the entire class in the variable you pass to `hoverColor` like

  ```
  <button
    className={`… ${props.hoverColor}`}>
  ```

  ```
  <Button hoverColor='hover:bg-gray' … />
  <Button hoverColor='hover:bg-light-gray' … />
  <Button hoverColor='hover:bg-light-gray' … />
  ```
- Have a dictionary for `color` to Tailwind class names:

  ```
  function Button(props) {
    const DICTIONARY = {
      'bg-gray': 'hover:bg-gray',
      'bg-light-gray': 'hover:bg-light-gray',
      // …
    };
    // …
    <button
      className={`… ${DICTIONARY[props.hoverColor]}`}>
  ```
- [`safelist` the classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes), if you have a limited number of known colors:

  ```js
  module.exports = {
    safelist: [
      {
        pattern: /^bg-((light-)?gray)$/,
        variants: ['hover'],
      },
      // …
    ],
    // …
  ];
  ```