# Colors Not Showing Up in React

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have made a card and i am sending colors , name, values init

No the issue is that it is given main color of all except card no 2 and no haver color and no lower color working for all but console shows me all colors

```
Card.jsx

import Icon from "@mdi/react";
import { mdiArrowRightCircle } from "@mdi/js";

function Card({ color, name, value }) {
  const [colorName, shade] = color.split('-');
  const lowerShade = (parseInt(shade) + 100).toString();
  const hoverShade = (parseInt(shade) + 200).toString();
  const mainColor = `bg-${colorName}-${shade}`;
  const lowerColor = `bg-${colorName}-${lowerShade}`;
  const hoverColor = `bg-${colorName}-${hoverShade}`;

  console.log("Main Color = "+ mainColor + "Lower Color = " + lowerColor +"Hover Color = " + hoverColor);

  return (
    <div className="h-full w-1/6 mx-2 rounded-lg overflow-hidden flex flex-col">
      <div className={`${mainColor} text-white flex flex-col h-5/6 px-4 pt-2`}>
        <span className="h-1/4">{name}</span>
        <span className="text-4xl font-semibold h-3/4 flex items-center">
          {value}
        </span>
      </div>
      <div className={`h-1/6 ${lowerColor} flex items-center justify-center hover:${hoverColor} text-white hover:cursor-pointer`}>
        <span>More info </span> <Icon path={mdiArrowRightCircle} size={1} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

```
Home.jsx

 <div className="h-1/6 flex">
          <Card  color={"gray-400"} name={"Risk Level %"} value={initialValue} />
          <Card  color={"teal-400"} name={"Number of Questions"} value={initialValue} />
          <Card  color={"yellow-400"} name={"LOW Level Questions"} value={initialValue} />
          <Card  color={"red-600"} name={"MEDIUM Level Questions"} value={initialValue} />
          <Card  color={"purple-600"} name={"HIGH Level Questions"} value={initialValue} />
          <Card  color={"slate-700"} name={"Other Level Questions"} value={initialValue} />

        </div>
```

Following is Shown on Console

```
Console 

Main Color = bg-gray-400 Lower Color = bg-gray-500 Hover Color = bg-gray-600
Main Color = bg-teal-400 Lower Color = bg-teal-500 Hover Color = bg-teal-600
Main Color = bg-yellow-400 Lower Color = bg-yellow-500 Hover Color = bg-yellow-600
Main Color = bg-red-600 Lower Color = bg-red-700 Hover Color = bg-red-800
Main Color = bg-purple-600 Lower Color = bg-purple-700 Hover Color = bg-purple-800
Main Color = bg-slate-700 Lower Color = bg-slate-800 Hover Color = bg-slate-900
```

Comment: Read this: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#class-detection-in-depth

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble with Dynamic Color in Tailwind Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76353036/trouble-with-dynamic-color-in-tailwind-component)

Comment: Yes it was very helpful and i have learned a lot Thanks @BarryMichaelDoyle

Comment: Glad it helped, yeah when I first started using tailwind that caught me out.

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could:

- Have the entire class in the variable you pass to `className` like

  ```
  function Card({ name, value, className = '', lowerClassName = '' }) {
    return (
      <div className="h-full w-1/6 mx-2 rounded-lg overflow-hidden flex flex-col">
        <div className={`${className} text-white flex flex-col h-5/6 px-4 pt-2`}>
          <span className="h-1/4">{name}</span>
          <span className="text-4xl font-semibold h-3/4 flex items-center">
            {value}
          </span>
        </div>
        <div className={`h-1/6 ${lowerClassName} flex items-center justify-center text-white hover:cursor-pointer`}>
  ```

  ```
  <Card className="bg-gray-400" lowerClassName="bg-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-600" … />
  <Card className="bg-teal-400" lowerClassName="bg-teal-500 hover:bg-teal-600" … />
  <Card className="bg-yellow-400" lowerClassName="bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yellow-600" … />
  <Card className="bg-red-600" lowerClassName="bg-red-700 hover:bg-red-800" … />
  <Card className="bg-purple-600" lowerClassName="bg-purple-700 hover:bg-purple-800" … />
  <Card className="bg-slate-700" lowerClassName="bg-slate-800 hover:bg-slate-900" … />
  ```
- Have a dictionary for `color` to Tailwind class names:

  ```
  function Card({ color, name, value }) {
    const DICTIONARY = {
      'gray-400': {
        mainColor: 'bg-gray-400',
        lowerColor: 'bg-gray-500',
        hoverColor: 'hover:bg-gray-600',
      },
      'teal-400': {
        mainColor: 'bg-teal-400',
        lowerColor: 'bg-teal-500',
        hoverColor: 'hover:bg-teal-600',
      },
      // …
    };

    const { mainColor, lowerColor, hoverColor } = DICTIONARY[color];
    // …
    return (
      <div className="h-full w-1/6 mx-2 rounded-lg overflow-hidden flex flex-col">
        <div className={`${mainColor} text-white flex flex-col h-5/6 px-4 pt-2`}>
          <span className="h-1/4">{name}</span>
          <span className="text-4xl font-semibold h-3/4 flex items-center">
            {value}
          </span>
        </div>
        <div className={`h-1/6 ${lowerColor} flex items-center justify-center ${hoverColor} text-white hover:cursor-pointer`}>
  ```
- [`safelist` the classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes), if you have a limited number of known colors:

  ```js
  module.exports = {
    safelist: [
      {
        pattern: /^bg-.+-\d+$/,
        variants: [
          'hover',
        ],
      },
      // …
    ],
    // …
  ];
  ```