# Tailwind doesn't apply

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

```
import fontColors from "@/styles-guide";

<p className={`text-[${fontColors.headerGray}] cursor-pointer hover:scale-105`}>About</p>
```

I declared as name "fontColors" variable another file. This file like that:

```
const fontColors = {
  headerGray: "#6A7A9B",
  primaryTextColor: "#4C86F0",
  secondaryTextColor: "#1B67F3",
  primaryButton: "#1B67F3",
};

export default fontColors;
```

I want to apply Tailwind property this component but it doesn't. If I write manually inside of component, it can apply. How can I solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble with Dynamic Color in Tailwind Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76353036/trouble-with-dynamic-color-in-tailwind-component)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could:

- Have the entire class in the variable you pass to `className` like:

  ```js
  const fontColors = {
    headerGray: "text-[#6A7A9B]",
    primaryTextColor: "text-[#4C86F0]",
    secondaryTextColor: "text-[#1B67F3]",
    primaryButton: "text-[#1B67F3]",
  };

  export default fontColors;
  ```

  ```
  <p className={`${fontColors.headerGray} …`}>
  ```

  Ensure **both** files that contain the above code are covered by the `content` file globs.
- Use the `style` attribute:

  ```
  <p className="…" style={{ color: fontColors.headerGray }}>
  ```
- [`safelist` the classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes), if you have a limited number of known colors:

  ```js
  module.exports = {
    safelist: [
      "text-[#6A7A9B]",
      "text-[#4C86F0]",
      "text-[#1B67F3]",
      "text-[#1B67F3]",
      // …
    ],
    // …
  ];
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solution was worked :)