# Tailwind animation is not working when passing animation-delay value through a variable

Tags: css, animation, tailwind-css, css-animations, tailwind-3

I was working with tailwind animation and I needed to create a custom animation in tailwind. The issue is that when I try to pass the value for the animation-delay using a variable or array, the animation does not seems to work. It does seems to work just fine when I explicitly gives the animation delay value.

If you are thinking that the variable value is not being passed correctly I assure you that it is passing correctly I have even checked in the chrome dev tools that the animation class is being applied.

And the most weird thing happening is that when I pass delay value 0.1,0.2 or 0.3 from the variable it works just fine. But if I try using any other value lets say 0.4,0.24,etc it will not work.

This is a really strange and weird issue I am having and had spent over a day on it but still nothing.

Keep in mind Its not the main issue the issue is very vast and I try to sum up the issue in a very simple example so restrain yourself from giving other possible solution. I do have other solution but I need this to work to make my animations dynamic.

Here is the Code that will not work as i am passing delay value 0.4

```
function AnimationBox() {
  const delay = 0.4;
  return (
    <div
      className={`flex h-80 w-full animate-[slideIn_0.5s_${delay}s_both] bg-white`}
    ></div>
  );
}

export default AnimationBox;
```

Here is the Code that will work as i am passing delay value 0.2 (because values like 0.1, 0.2 and 0.3 works just fine)

```
function AnimationBox() {
  const delay = 0.2;
  return (
    <div
      className={`flex h-80 w-full animate-[slideIn_0.5s_${delay}s_both] bg-white`}
    ></div>
  );
}

export default AnimationBox;
```

Here is the Code that will also work  as i am giving delay value explicitly and no matter the value it will work just fine.

```
function AnimationBox() {

  return (
    <div
      className={`flex h-80 w-full animate-[slideIn_0.5s_0.123s_both] bg-white`}
    ></div>
  );
}

export default AnimationBox;
```

I just need a reason why its not working and to understand what is thing behaviour.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble with Dynamic Color in Tailwind Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76353036/trouble-with-dynamic-color-in-tailwind-component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

Some values work (like `0.1`, `0.2`) because you have some complete class names else where like `animate-[slideIn_0.5s_0.1s_both]` that **don't** use string interpolation and are written as-is. The usage with the string interpolation then "piggy-backs" off this, and thus purely coincidental that it works for these values.

To make it work, you could:

- Use the `style` attribute:

  ```
  <div
    className="… animate-[slideIn_0.5s_both] …"
    style={{ animationDelay: `${delay}s` }}
  >
  ```
- [`safelist` the classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes), if you have a limited number of known values:

  ```js
  module.exports = {
    safelist: [
      'animate-[slideIn_0.5s_0.1s_both]',
      'animate-[slideIn_0.5s_0.2s_both]',
      'animate-[slideIn_0.5s_0.3s_both]',
      'animate-[slideIn_0.5s_0.4s_both]',
    ],
    // …
  ];
  ```

Comment: Thanx for you response it really really helped and I can see you have in-depth knowledge of tailwind. 
I too came to the solution of removing my delay value and giving it separately but what I did wrong was I gave the delay value as a tailwind class something like:

`className = '... animate-[slideIn_0.5s_both] delay-[${delay}] ...'`

Which was not going to work as I am following the law of not breaking tailwind classes as you told me.

And also I did not knew that we could use CSS on the tailwind classes i.e inline css or style tag. That is why I was unable to find any solution.