# Inconsistent Tailwind behavior

Tags: css, laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I'm working on a livewire project, trying to apply some tailwind theme configuration, but it just doesn't make sense at all.
This is my Tailwind configuration:

```
theme: {
    extend: {
        fontFamily: {
            sans: ['Figtree', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
        },
        colors: {
            'blue':  {
                light: '#bae6fd',
                DEFAULT: '#38bdf8',
                dark: '#0369a1'
            },
            'red': '#be123c'
        }
    },
}
```

Then I have this button component

```
@props(['color' => 'gray'])

@php
    $classes = 'bg-' . $color . ' hover:bg-' . $color . '-dark inline-flex items-center 
               px-3 py-2 border-transparent rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white 
              uppercase tracking-widest focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring- 
              indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-2 transition ease-in-out duration-150'
@endphp

<button {{ $attributes->merge([
            'type'  => 'submit',
            'class' => $classes
        ]) }}>
    {{ $slot }}
</button>
```

Here is the button used

```
<x-button color="blue">{{ __('Edit') }}</x-button>
```

And here is what happens:

- run `npm run build` : background white, style classes do not work
- run `npm run build` again: style properties picked up and works as expected
- run it again: stops working, background is white and no hover effect is applied
- change the button's color property to red and run `npm run build`: it works, but no hover
- change it back to blue and run command: doesn't work , it completely stopped recognizing the blue theme colors
- change to red and run command: works
  .....
- at some point it stops working even with the red color, hard to keep track of the behaviour.

It feels very unstable, but possible that my approach is wrong, as I'm expecting it to behave as it would with a FE js framework.

Any suggestion and information is much appreciated.

Comment: @brombeer good spot, but my code does not have the quotes. That was my typo mistake here, removed them now. My configuration looks exactly as suggested in the Tailwind's documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble with Dynamic Color in Tailwind Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76353036/trouble-with-dynamic-color-in-tailwind-component)

Answer (score 0):

#### Missing color definitions

Many of the colors you have tried do not exist with your Tailwind configuration. Of the ones you mention, `bg-gray`, `bg-gray-dark` and `bg-red-dark` do not exist, only `bg-red`, `bg-blue` and `bg-blue-dark` would exist.

You'd need to add the other colors like:

```js
theme: {
  extend: {
    fontFamily: {
      sans: ['Figtree', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
    },
    colors: {
      'blue':  {
        light: '#bae6fd',
        DEFAULT: '#38bdf8',
        dark: '#0369a1'
      },
      red: {
        DEFAULT: '#be123c',
        dark: '…',
      },
      gray: {
        DEFAULT: '…',
        dark: '…',
      },
    }
  },
}
```

#### Dynamic class name construction

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could:

- Have the entire class in the variable you pass to `color` like

  ```php
  @props(['color' => 'bg-gray hover:bg-gray-dark'])

  @php
    $classes = $color . ' inline-flex items-center …'
  @endphp
  ```

  ```php
  <x-button color="bg-blue hover:bg-blue-dark">{{ __('Edit') }}</x-button>
  ```
- Have a dictionary for `color` to Tailwind class names:

  ```php
  @props(['color' => 'gray'])

  @php
    $dictionary = [
      'gray' => 'bg-gray hover:bg-gray-dark',
      'blue' => 'bg-blue hover:bg-blue-dark',
      …
    ];
    $classes = $dictionary[$color] . ' inline-flex items-center …'
  @endphp
  ```
- [`safelist` the classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes), if you have a limited number of known colors:

  ```js
  module.exports = {
    safelist: [
      { pattern: /^bg-(gray|blue|…)$/ },
      {
        pattern: /^bg-(gray|blue|…)-dark$/,
        variants: ['hover'],
      },
      // …
    ],
    // …
  ];
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I read about the issue with dynamic class names, wasn't sure how overcoming it. Let me try the options you suggested, but they are pretty much the same to what I did, only difference is that you concatenated the classes as single string while I added multiple concatenation operators. Fingers crossed, maybe works. If it does I might ask for further explanation. The color definitions are correct  I never expected the hover class to work when it's set to 'red' . My issue was that I set it to 'red', then when setting it back to 'blue' it didn't recognize the class names