# Unable to render Tailwind CSS properties dynamically

Tags: javascript, next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to render Tailwind CSS properties dynamically and the class is being applied in the browser inspector but the color is not changing.

I have a function that takes as input an rarity (tier) and returns the Tailwind CSS property that shows the color of that tier:

```
export function checkRarity(tier: string) {
  const rarityLookup = new Map([
    ["COMMON", "text-rarity-common"],
    ["UNCOMMON", "text-rarity-uncommon"],
    ["RARE", "text-rarity-rare"],
    ["EPIC", "text-rarity-epic"],
    ["LEGENDARY", "text-rarity-legendary"],
    ["MYTHIC", "text-rarity-mythic"],
    ["DIVINE", "text-rarity-divine"],
    ["SPECIAL", "text-rarity-special"],
    ["VERY_SPECIAL", "text-rarity-very-special"],
  ]);

  return rarityLookup.get(tier) || "bg-gray-400";
}
```

Then I am trying merge the manually typed property and and the dynamic one using twMerge and clsx as I seen at [dynamically-build-classnames-in-tailwindcss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69687530/dynamically-build-classnames-in-tailwindcss/76660733#76660733).

This is the function:

```
export function cn(...inputs: ClassValue[]) {
  return twMerge(clsx(inputs));
}
```

And here I am trying to call the function to merge the Tailwind classes:

```
const textColor = cn("text-2xl", checkRarity(auction.tier));
```

Then here I am applying the className:

```
<h2 className={textColor}>
            {text}        
 </h2>
```

I have tried the following things to fix the issue:

- I have checked the spelling of the Tailwind classes.
- I have made sure that the Tailwind classes are defined in my Tailwind configuration file.
- I have tried using different names for the dynamic Tailwind class.

But for some reason the only Tailwind class that works is text-rarity-legendary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tailwind doesn’t include any sort of client-side runtime, so class names need to be statically extractable at build-time, and can’t depend on any sort of arbitrary dynamic values that change on the client.

You can use inline styles for these situations:

```
export function checkRarity(tier: string) {
   const rarityLookup = new Map([
      ['COMMON', '#fff'],
      //...
   ]);

   return rarityLookup.get(tier) || '#fff';
}
```