# Tailwind problem backgroundImage not loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, background-image

I have a problem with tailwind. I'm working with React and i wanted to chnage the image with a map and the id  so i did a .json file:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "...",
    "description": "...",
    "link": "/work"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "...",
    "description": "...",
    "link": "/work"
  },
```

after that i map it in my file like this

```
{card.map((card) => (
<Link
          to="/work"
          key="1"
          className={`relative w-[576px] h-[320px] bg-cover rounded-xl overflow-hidden bg-COVER${card.id}  group transition-all ease-in duration-300`}
>
        ...
</Link>
))}
```

as you can see there is COVER${card.id} and in the tailwind.config.js file i did this

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      proggy: ["Proggy", "monospace"],
    },
    extend: {},
    backgroundImage: {
      COVER1: "url('./assets/test1.jpg')",
      COVER2: "url('./assets/test2.jpg')",
      COVER3: "url('./assets/test3.jpg')",
      COVER4: "url('./assets/test4.jpg')",
      COVER5: "url('./assets/test5.jpg')",
      COVER6: "url('./assets/test6.jpg')",
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

This is not working properly

I tried to do this

```
{card.map((card) => (
<Link
          to="/work"
          key="1"
          className={`relative w-[576px] h-[320px] bg-cover rounded-xl overflow-hidden bg-COVER1  group transition-all ease-in duration-300`}
>
        ...
</Link>
))}
```

and it is working, after i undo this and make it like this

```
{card.map((card) => (
<Link
          to="/work"
          key="1"
          className={`relative w-[576px] h-[320px] bg-cover rounded-xl overflow-hidden bg-COVER${card.id}  group transition-all ease-in duration-300`}
>
        ...
</Link>
))}
```

the first image is now working
I think the problem is from the loading of the image but don't understand how to fix it if you need more file i can.

Comment: Have you tried to console log the COVER${card.id} to see if is working properly?

Answer (score 0):

TailwindCSS generates the stylesheet by scanning through your source code and adding all used classes. But since you're not actually writing them out, it doesn't "see" them.
You can read about some solutions in the docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

There's also this related question: [Dynamically build classnames in TailwindCss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69687530/dynamically-build-classnames-in-tailwindcss)

For your specific use-case I would recommend not using Tailwind for your covers, but instead setting the background in the [style parameter](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style)

You could try something like this:

```
<Link className="..." style={{
   backgroundImage: "url(...)"
}} />
```