# Tailwindcss extracting classes with @apply are not being applied when injecting a className to a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

When injecting a className of a predefined tailwind class the style is not applied.

I have defined multiple classes in my globals.css for example:

```
   .card-neutral {
        @apply bg-neutral100 inline-flex shrink grow basis-0 cursor-pointer flex-col items-center justify-center self-stretch rounded-lg border border-neutral-200 p-3;
    }

    .card-neutral-section {
        @apply text-neutral1000
    }

    .card-neutral-head {
        @apply text-neutral800
    }

    .card-neutral-paragraph {
        @apply text-neutral500
    }
```

all the text-colors are nested classes defined like this:

```
 .text-neutral100 {
        @apply text-lightneutral100 dark:text-darkneutral100;
     }
```

I have a compound component that gets a theme passed like "neutral" and sets the classnames of its parent and its subcomponents to these classes.

The Card Compound component:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext } from 'react'

const CardContext = createContext()

const Card = ({ children, theme }) => {
    return (
        <div className={` card-${theme}`}>
            <CardContext.Provider value={{ theme }}>
                {children}
            </CardContext.Provider>
        </div>
    )
}

const Section = ({ children }) => {
    const { theme } = useContext(CardContext)

    return <div className={`card-${theme}-section`}>{children}</div>
}

const Head = ({ children }) => {
    const { theme } = useContext(CardContext)

    return <h2 className={`card-${theme}-head`}>{children}</h2>
}

const Paragraph = ({ children }) => {
    const { theme } = useContext(CardContext)

    return <p className={`card-${theme}-paragraph`}>{children}</p>
}

Card.Section = Section
Card.Head = Head
Card.Paragraph = Paragraph

export default Card
```

I can see in my Browser tools that the classNames are passed properly but the classes are never applied. But if I hardcode the className inside my subcomponents the classes are applied. It seems to be a reference or timing issues but I cannot find a solution.

Is this even a good way to approach a "themeable" card component or is there an easier way that I am not seeing at the moment?

Edit:

Found a solution here: [Dynamically build classnames in TailwindCss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69687530/dynamically-build-classnames-in-tailwindcss)